# Find element on site from a fancybox iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, fancybox

I'm trying to update a element on my site from a fancybox. In the fancybox i do a `$.post()` and get back `html` data that i want to populate in a div on my page. I open up a `iframe` window with `html` and this script below is in that `iframe`. It cant find it from the fancybox so anybody got idea or solution on how to reach a element thats not inside the fancybox `iframe`?

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this).closest('form');

    $.post($this.attr('action'), { quantity: $this.find('#quantity_id').val() }, function (data) {
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
        $('#container').html(data);
    }, 'html');

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#container', $(parent.document)).html(data);
```