# Update an element on parent page from fancybox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update a Select Box on Parent Page from FancyBox2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188974/update-a-select-box-on-parent-page-from-fancybox2)

I'm trying to update an element on my site from a fancybox. In the fancybox I do a $.post() and get back html data that aI want to populate in a div on my page. I'm opening the fancybox in ajax. I can see in firebug that my script is returning the html but the select box on the parent page is not updating. Can anyone help me with the proper way to do that? I'm currently trying from the fancybox:

```
$("#send-message").click(function () {
      $(this).closest('form').submit(function () {
          return false;
      });
      var frm = $(this).closest('form');
      if ($(frm).valid()) {
          $("#ajax-loading").show();
          var data = $(frm).serialize();
          $(frm).find('textarea,select,input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          $.post("../forms/company_add.php",
          data,

          function (data) {
              if (data.success) {
                  $('#companyselect', $(parent.document)).html(data.success);
                  parent.$.fancybox.close();
              } else {
                  $("#ajax-loading").hide();
                  $(frm).find('textarea,select,input').removeAttr('disabled');
                  $("#send_message_frm").append(data.error);
              }
          }, "json"

          );
      }
  });
```

I'm using fancybox-2 and php. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use the id of the element

```
$('#companyselect').html(data.success);
$.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: I believe your answer will work as well. I went with:    $('div.companyselect', $(parent.document)).html(data.success); which works but the reason it wasn't earlier had to do with broken html, not the wrong selector.

Answer (score 0):

Write a javascript function on your parent like

```
function UpdateElementOfParent(someValue)
{
// your code
}
```

And from your fancybox, you can the object of parent and call its function like that..

```
this.parent.UpdateElementOfParent(someValue);
```